# Approaches for shades on large skylights

Tags: windows, skylight

I have a few skylights large enough that nearly all manufactured skylight shades (both mechanical and motorized) won't fit.  That is, for widths larger than 24", most manufacturers of skylight shades won't offer lengths over 60".

That limit, of course, makes sense.  Wide cel shades over long runs tend to sag even if the fabric is supported by a central line.

What then can I do to shade a finished skylight opening of 83.5” length x 42.5” width?

I'll entertain any and all options, from off-the-shelf products to building something from scratch.  My main concern is getting something that will be able to open and close regularly, and easily.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecwkDSvlnMY

Comment: Interior of exterior? What is the purpose? If they're to cut down on heat, they have to be exterior. To cut down on light, they can be either. I just built myself exterior louvereds to cut down on summer heat, but won't go into details not knowing the answers. One was a 46" wide Velux, the other 28" wide.

Comment: Thanks for your questions -- to answer, I am thinking of interior shades to reduce light.  I've actually never heard of exterior shades -- do you mean that you've mounted louvres on your roof?  That sounds awfully hard to maintain, or operate.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you completely...

Comment: That's certainly a nice, cheap option.  However, UV and heat will cook almost any material used for such a 'tarp' approach, in short order.  Also, I said 'My main concern is getting something that will be able to open and close regularly, and easily.' -- and these can't open at all...

Comment: how high is the ceiling where skylights are? The cheap cloth is great cause yiu just cut a new one. I’m thinking a track could be made to slide it back and forth with a cord if it’s not too high

Comment: The ceiling slopes from ~9' at the low end to ~15' at the high end.  A track or rails on the sides with attachments to the cloth tarp every few inches could work as you suggest.  The drape would hang in fullness (pleated at the attachments) in the open/uncovered skylight position and straight when unfolded in the closed/covered skylight position.  But does anyone have a trick to keep the pleats on the left and right sides moving together, to prevent the thing from binding when opening or closing?

Comment: Not all materials are UV-vulnerable. Being defeatist guarantees failure.

Comment: True!  Still, if you've spent any time close to the glass of a large skylight in summer, then you know that the temperatures can be pretty extreme.  I've been amazed at what sunlight can do over time.  ;-)